# Change custom element content before and after attaching to the DOM

Tags: javascript, custom-element, html-templates

I created a custom HTML element that creates a new element from the following template:

```
<template id="track">
  <div class="record">Nothing yet</div>
</template>
```

Here the JS code that defines the custom element:

```
class Track extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();    
    this.template = document.getElementById("track");
    this.clone = this.template.content.cloneNode(true);
  }
    
  connectedCallback() {    
    this.append( this.clone );
  }
  
  set record(html) { 
    // Case 1: Works only for element 1 (before appending to the DOM)
    this.clone.querySelector('.record').innerHTML = html;
    // Case 2: Works only for element 2 (after appending to the DOM)
    //this.querySelector('.record').innerHTML = html;
  }
}


customElements.define('my-track', Track);
```

Note the record property that changes the HTML content of the `<div>`. I would like to be able to update the element content whatever it has been attached or not the DOM. I can't write a code that works in both cases (before and after appending the custom element to the DOM). The following code only works in case 1:

```
const el1 = document.createElement('my-track');
el1.record = "Bla<b>bla</b> #1";
document.body.append(el1);
```

The following code only works in case 2

```
const el2 = document.createElement('my-track');
document.body.append(el2);
el2.record = "Bla<b>bla</b> #2";
```

Of course, in the method `set record()`, I could check if the element has already been attached to the DOM and switch to case 1 or case 2 accordingly. But I feel this is not the right way to build custom elements.

What is the best option to update element content in the method `set record()` whether or not the element has been attached to the DOM ?

I create a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Alphonsio/gL8a239o/13/

Comment: `template` requires `querySelector` off of the `content` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write anything to DOM when there is no DOM.

Just like you can not put a sofa in your livingroom when there is no house yet.

That means you have to check with `this.isConnected` if the element is attached to the DOM, in the `set record` method.

Its an instance of a JavaScript class/object; You can of course attach *anything* you want to it and have the `constructor/attributeChangedCallback/connectedCallback` process it (but really think trough the house/livingroom scenario)

Note ***shadowDOM*** allows you to create any DOM you want and **not** have it display in the main DOM (yet) (same applies to a DocumentFragment)

```js
const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

customElements.define('my-track', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.warn("connectedCallback" , this.id);
    this.append(
      this.recordDIV = createElement("div", {
        innerHTML: `Default Record content`
      }))
  }

  set record(html) {
    if (this.isConnected)
      this.recordDIV.innerHTML = html;
    else
      console.warn(this.id, "Not in the DOM yet")
  }
});

const el1 = createElement('my-track', { id: "el1" });
el1.record = "Record " + el1.id;
document.body.append(el1);

const el2 = createElement('my-track', { id: "el2" });
document.body.append(el2);
el2.record = "Record " + el2.id;
```

### Added shadowDOM example

Or build your own https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

```js
const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

customElements.define('my-track', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
    .append(
      this.recordDIV = createElement("div",{
        innerHTML: `Default Record content ` + this.id      
      })
    )
  }

  set record(html) {
    this.recordDIV.innerHTML = html;
  }
});

const el1 = createElement('my-track', { id: "el1" });
el1.record = "Record " + el1.id;
document.body.append(el1);

const el2 = createElement('my-track', { id: "el2" });
document.body.append(el2);
el2.record = "Record " + el2.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this does not answer to my question. In the case 1, I want to prepare the element in background before appending the elemen to the DOM. Not displaying a warning in the console

Comment: *you can not put a sofa in your living room when there is no house yet* In the question he modifes the document fragment, so it can be done.

Comment: Then a shadowDOM, as I said, is an option. Or you have to construct you own ``new DocumentFragment()``